# Bootstrap horizontal form is ignoring container-fluid padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, `container-fluid` has some padding, which I want. However, things inside a horizontal form seem to be ignoring the padding and getting pushed all the way to the edges of the container (I've added a border to the container here for illustration):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="max-width:900px;border:1px solid black">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">Correct, obeys container-fluid padding.</div>
  <form class="form form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group alert alert-danger">Too Wide</div>
    <div class="form-group panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Too Wide</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Body</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Too far left</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

A working example [is on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ECCyM7OFyE).

In that example, the first alert is as intended. Everything else inside the `form` is too wide.

Now, not shown in the Bootply, but if I add an input to the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field">Label</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="field" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The input *is* padded correctly, unlike the alerts and panels, which I don't understand.

How do I get all the things in the form to obey the padding? This is especially important to me because on small screens it pushes everything right to the edge and doesn't look that great.

The only thing I could think of to try was enclosing the form in a plain `div`, which had no effect.

I also achieved some success by manually setting the padding on the form, but that doesn't feel right, and it also breaks the properly padded input elements. Plus, it's not too robust in that I can't guarantee my hard-coded padding will match the container's usual padding which I have no control over.

Comment: for the "too wide" stuff, remove `form-group` from the classes.

Comment: for the "too far left" button, just remove that class name altogether and keep the div; worked for me in your test fiddle.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That does work, thanks. So I guess `form-group` is *only* for use around label+input pairs? Also if you wanna post that as an answer; I've got a couple good answers below already too (well, one deleted, but still valid), I'm looking into all of them now to see which one looks to be the "right" way to do it, should put yours in that list too.

Comment: You're welcome Jason. It's ok. The answer given contains a better explanation then I could give. TBH, I don't know the full logistics on those, I only do a lot of "trial and error" tests to see "what gives". However, if you insist that my comments would be the shortest solution rather than "adding" stuff, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//This will sort out your panels and alerts. (.less code)
//Or you could just put a .col-xs-12 on them.
.form-horizontal {
  > .panel,
  > .alert {
    margin: 0 @grid-gutter-width / 2; //(or just 15px if your using bootstrap dist)
  }        
}
```

Then for your input groups, just using the `col-sm-2` on your labels like you have done above.

And for your form group with the submit button simple put a `col-xs-12` on it.

The reason for this is: .`form-groups` inside `.form-horizontal` receive `margin-left: -15px;` (The same as grid-gutter-width).

The intended design is that you use form-horizontal as a substitute for a .row and then use .cols inside. Or implement how you choose to fit your design.

Reference : [bootstrap forms horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Do your inputs like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Do your submit button like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do your alerts like this if you like

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <!-- alert here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I think your other answer was actually more concise. The issue is that in a `form-horizontal` the `form-group` acts as a `row` and performs a `margin-left:-15px` and `margin-right:-15px` because it expects that the `label` and the corresponding `:input `element are wrapped in `columns`.

Comment: I see; so, should I be enclosing the alerts and panels and stuff in a `<div class="row">` (or even just making them "row" instead of "form-group")? And then only using "form-group" instead of "row" for label/input pairs?

Comment: Nop don't enclose them in a row. enclose them in a col-xs-12. That will give you the side padding you need. I'll update my answer with how you can format it

Comment: Wait, no, using "row" instead doesn't work. But adding that style does. Also just removing "form-group" from all but the label/input pair and adding no styles also works (like [Fred mentioned in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092145/bootstrap-horizontal-form-is-ignoring-container-fluid-padding?noredirect=1#comment69389600_41092145)).

Comment: Oh I think I understand now. http://www.bootply.com/BL2otvnuJ4 - I add column specifiers to everything, don't use "row" anywhere, and drop the "form-group" everywhere but the label+input. That seems... more sensible.